# Android Studio: Error running 'myProject': The application could not be installed

Tags: android, android-studio

My application does not run on an emulator and a real device, and there are no details of the error. I tried all the tips I found on ~20 google pages, but nothing helped. Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?
At the same time .apk builds and works great if I install it separately.

[Error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM1wO.png)

I changed the adb ports, I changed the flags and startup parameters, I cleaned the cache, I reinstalled Windows. Nothing helped

UPD: Logcat show this:

```
2023-12-05 11:22:24.528  8108-8108  Parcel                  pid-8108                             E  Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2023-12-05 11:22:25.974   144-163   Netd                    netd                                 E  Failed to dump IPv4 sockets struct tcp_info: No such file or directory
2023-12-05 11:22:25.974   144-163   TcpSocketMonitor        netd                                 E  Failed to poll TCP socket info: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you please show more details about the error on installation? Also check if your device has enough free space to install.

Comment: AS does not show the details of this error. There's only what's in the screenshot, and I don't understand what my problem is at all. Yes, there is enough free space

Comment: @Александр - When using a different Android Studio version, does installation work?

Comment: @tomerpacific no. I used giraffe and hedgehog, but the problem remained